# What is「~(よう)とするも」?

Tags: grammar

A chapter summary from Kanokari chapter 191

> カオスづくしの家簇簇行がいよいよスタート!! ハワイアンズへの道中で、水原が指輪を返そうと**するも**俺は断{ことわ}った!! 俺はこの旅行中に水原に告白するんだ・・・!!と改めて気持ちを引き締めたんだけど、 ホテルに着いたらロビーに麻美ちゃんが!! なんで!?

What is the meaning of するも here? Can I understand it as する**の**も?

Comment: It's a literary way of saying 返そうとしたが. This use of するも sounds a little theatrical to me.

Comment: Thanks for confirming! I wasn't too sure at first.